# How to set a native attribute from AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to write HTML similar to:

```
<a href="sharedasset: img.png">test</a>
<img src="sharedasset: img.png"/>
```

And have a directive called "sharedasset" that gets the full path to `img.png` and sets the value of the attribute without the directive having any knowledge of what the attribute name is ahead of time. Is this possible?

**Update**

Since I originally posted this there have been some improvements to Angular and I thought I'd share what I do now as a result. In the HTML I use Guido Bouman's answer which is to create a filter and, now with Angular's *bind once* feature, this makes it the best option in my opinion.

In the JS code though, instead of injecting `$filter` and my `globalVars` constant everywhere, now I just prepend the word `static` to any path of an asset that is hosted on the static content server like `{templateUrl: "static/someTemplate.html"}` and then use an Angular HTTP Interceptor to look for any path that begins with "static" and replace it with the domain for the static server. Very simple.

Comment: How about `<a ng-href="{{fullPath}}img.png">` and `<img ng-src="{{fullPath}}img.png">`?  This would require `fullPath` to be defined in a controller.

Comment: I want fullPath to be defined in the directive though.

Comment: The directive can't be used inside the value of href or src.

Comment: But on http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive at the top they have the example `<span class="my-dir: exp;"></span>`. How are they doing it?

Comment: It can be used as a class.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
<a full-path="img.png">test</a>
<img full-path="img.png">
```

```
app.directive('fullPath', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fullPathUrl = "http://.../";
            if(element[0].tagName === "A") {
                attrs.$set('href',fullPathUrl + attrs.fullPath);
            } else {
                attrs.$set('src',fullPathUrl + attrs.fullPath);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

I don't know where you are getting `fullPathUrl` from, so I hardcoded it in the link function.

Comment: This is close, but it has 'href' hard-coded in the directive. What if I want to use the directive on an `<img src=""`?

Comment: @adam0101, define another directive, or make the one directive smarter to check the tag type:  `if(element[0].tagName === "A") { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't want the directive to care what the attribute name was, so this is what I ended up doing:

```
<a shared-asset="images/img.png" attr="href">test</a>
<img shared-asset="images/img.png" />
```

```
app.directive('sharedAsset', function (globalVars) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            attr: "@attr"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var fullPath = globalVars.staticWebsite + "/app/styles/main/" + attrs.sharedAsset + "?build=" + globalVars.buildNumber;

            attrs.$set(scope.attr || "src", fullPath);
        }
    };
});
```

**Update**: I changed it to default to the "src" attribute since images will be the most common scenario.

Comment: So you do practically the same thing as Mark but mark your own answer as the answer. Very nice.

Comment: @Blackunknown, because his answer didn't answer my question. I specifically stated that the attribute name couldn't be known ahead of time but he had it hard-coded. I upvoted his answer because it helped, but marked mine as the answer because it answered my question.

Comment: In my opinion he gave you the answer still. All you did was add in a variable instead of it being hard-coded. A lot of the answers people give here are not going to be 100% what you want in the end. Plus the difference is so minimal.

Comment: Whatever, it doesn't matter to me. I just figured the next visitor would want to see the answer that best answered the question.

Answer (score 8):

A custom filter is much more suited for this case than a directive:

```
<a href="{{'images/img.png' | fullPath}}">test</a>
<img src="{{'images/img.png' | fullPath}}" />
```

The filter: (Assuming you have a global `filters` module)

```
angular.module('filters').filter('fullPath', function(globalVars) {
  return function(url) {
    return globalVars.staticWebsite + "/app/styles/main/" + url + "?build=" + globalVars.buildNumber;
  };
});
```

Comment: I really like this approach. I'll probably do it this way on my next project. I'm assuming if you need to do it programmatically you could use `$filter('fullPath')('images/img.png')` then?

Comment: Yes, that's an advantage as well.