# Populate list item attributes from an AngularJS directive with access to parent's controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is an HTML fragment that I would like to replace with an AnguarJS directive:

```
<li ng-click="ctrl.navigate('home')"
    ng-mouseenter="ctrl.mouseOver = 'home'"
    ng-mouseleave="ctrl.mouseOver = ''"
    ng-class="{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === 'home'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === 'home')}">Home</li>
```

Having defined my directive I was hoping that the above code would become

```
<li navigation-selection selection-name="home" selection-content="Home" />
```

To achieve this I added a directive template file `navigationselection.html` containing this HTML fragment

```
<li ng-click="ctrl.navigate('{{selectionName}}')"
    ng-mouseenter="ctrl.mouseOver = '{{selectionName}}'"
    ng-mouseleave="ctrl.mouseOver = ''"
    ng-class="{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === '{{selectionName}}'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === '{{selectionName}}')}">{{selectionTitle}}</li>
```

and this directive:

```
    .directive('navigationSelection', [function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/navigationselection.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                selectionName: '@',
                selectionTitle: '@'
            }
        };
    }]);
```

But the resulting HTML has one list item nested within another:

```
<li navigation-selection="navigation-selection" selection-name="home" selection-title="Thing 1" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <li ng-click="ctrl.navigate('home')" ng-mouseenter="ctrl.mouseOver = 'home'" ng-mouseleave="ctrl.mouseOver = ''" ng-class="{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === 'home'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === 'home')}" class="ng-binding">Home</li>
</li>
```

(N.B. I have added the line breaks for readability.)

If I add `replace: true` to my directive definition object then it works: the inner list item completely replaces its parent. But, as [the AngularJS directive documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.11/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-) points out, `replace` is depricated and will be removed in next major release.

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219467/575530) to adam0101’s question [How to set a native attribute from AngularJS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18218956/575530) Mark Rajcok shows how to do this using the directive's `link` function. And so if I replace the directive template with just

```
{{selectionTitle}}
```

and extend the directive with this link function

```
    .directive('navigationSelection', [function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/navigationselection.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                selectionName: '@',
                selectionTitle: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$set('ng-click', "ctrl.navigate('" + attrs.selectionName + "')");
                attrs.$set('ng-mouseenter', "ctrl.mouseOver = '" + attrs.selectionName + "'");
                attrs.$set('ng-mouseleave', "ctrl.mouseOver = ''");
                attrs.$set('ng-class', "{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === '" + attrs.selectionName + "'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === '" + attrs.selectionName + "')}");
            }
        };
    }]);
```

It should work. But it doesn't. The resulting HTML looks very similar to my pre-directive version above:

```
<li navigation-selection="navigation-selection" selection-name="home" selection-title="Home" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" ng-click="ctrl.navigate('home')" ng-mouseenter="ctrl.mouseOver = 'home'" ng-mouseleave="ctrl.mouseOver = ''" ng-class="{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === 'home'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === 'home')}">Home</li>
```

but the events, e.g. `ng-click`, no longer work. I wonder if this is because I've lost access to `ctrl` when I provided a `scope` in my directive definition object.

How do I use an AngularJS directive, without `replace` to add attributes and content to a list item such that the event directives like `ng-click` can still call methods on the parent's controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are scope issues; I needed to keep the original scope and not add an isolated scope without passing in the controller.

But I had also [misunderstood the life-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627233/575530) and so the directives added as attributes by my custom directive are never themselves compiled and I need to do that explicitly. This code fixes things:

```
    .directive('navigationSelection', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.removeAttr('navigation-selection'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
                element[0].innerText = attrs.selectionTitle;
                attrs.$set('ng-click', "ctrl.navigate('" + attrs.selectionName + "')");
                attrs.$set('ng-mouseenter', "ctrl.mouseOver = '" + attrs.selectionName + "'");
                attrs.$set('ng-mouseleave', "ctrl.mouseOver = ''");
                attrs.$set('ng-class', "{'over' : (ctrl.mouseOver === '" + attrs.selectionName + "'), 'selected' : (ctrl.selected === '" + attrs.selectionName + "')}");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        };
    }]);
```