# AngularJS: How to set an attribute to a custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive which holds a `<textarea>` element along with other HTML elements in its template using `templateUrl`. This directive should allow a user to type with any *Indian Language (using any writing script like [devanagri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) and others)*. The user will get to select the input language.

This directive will be used like this in my HTML:`<keybuddy></keybuddy>`

Now my problem is, in my main code, **how should I retrieve the text entered in the `textarea` that is located in the template.html specified by `templateUrl`?** I have the text available in the scope of my link function since I used `ng-model` on the `textarea`.

```
<textarea id="inputField"
          placeholder="start typing....."
          ng-model="inputText"
          rows="5">
</textarea>
```

In my `index.html`, I should be able to do something like this:

```
<keybuddy></keybuddy>
<button onclick="printText()">Show Text</button>

<script>
    var printText = function () {
        console.log($("keybuddy").value);
    }
</script>
```

How do I do it? Is there any other better way using the power of AngularJS? I went through these posts but wasn't helpful. Or might be I could not understand how to use it in my work. [How to set a native attribute from AngularJS directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218956/how-to-set-a-native-attribute-from-angularjs-directive), [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

> my complete code on github: [keybuddy](https://github.com/shirishparsekar/keybuddy.git)

Note:

- I should be able to use this directive anywhere in the application, any number of times.
- It should be portable; I should be able to use it in any of my project or any other developer should be able to use it without much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Angular :-)

You don't need the use of jQuery here. Angular is sufficient enough. You can change your code like this:

In your View:

```
<keybuddy model="myInputText"></keybuddy>

<button ng-click="showText()">Show Text</button>
```

In your View controller:

```
$scope.showText = function() {
    console.log($scope.myInputText);
}
```

And update your directive to have `scope` like below (replace your `scope: true):

```
scope: {
    inputText: '=model'
}
```

Read more on [Isolating scope of a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a bi-directional binding to the directive scope.  This will allow your directive to change a value in the parent scope, which you can then read from your controller.

In your directives configuration setup the scope property with the name of an attribute to use for the binding, such as:

```
scope: { 
    model: '='
}
```

In your directive's template then you can set the textarea's ng-model to that binding name.

```
<textarea ng-model="model"></textarea>
```

In the parent where you use the directive, pass the attribute you configured set to the name of a variable on the scope.

```
<keybuddy model="inputText"></keybuddy>
```

Then in your controller you can access the textarea's current content by reading `$scope.inputText`.

```
$scope.printText = function(){
    alert($scope.inputText);
}
```

Template:

```
<button ng-click="printText();">Print text</button>
```

Comment: What when I use `<keybuddy>` twice in an HTML? I need to retrieve textarea values from both instances separately.

Comment: Just assign them separate variables on the scope.  `<keybuddy model="inputText1"></keybuddy>` and `<keybuddy model="inputText2"></keybuddy>`.   Use `$scope.inputText1` and `$scope.inputText2` to read the values.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's already in the scope, you could simply use

```
console.log($("keybuddy textarea").scope().inputText);
```

AngularJS version:

```
console.log(angular.element("keybuddy textarea").scope().inputText);
```

EDIT: Adapted to match the actual source code.

Comment: I need textarea's value where I'm calling it